# C++ pass pointer to member as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a bunch of very similar functions:

```cpp
void foo1(Obj o) {
    bar(o.a);
}

void foo2(Obj2 o) {
    bar(o.b);
}

void foo3(Obj3 o) {
    bar(o.c);
}
```

How can I reduce the duplicating of code? Can I do something like:

```cpp
template<typename T, pointerToMember>
void foo(T o) {
    bar(o.pointerToMember);
}
```

And then create all functions like:

```
foo<Obj, Obj.x>;
...
```

?

Comment: what is `a`, `b` and `c`? Why not pass them directly?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: what is the purpose of `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` anyhow? Why not call `bar` directly?

Comment: Why not make the pointer to member a function parameter?  `template<typename T, typename U>
void foo(T o, U T::* foo) {
    bar(o.*foo);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have a pointer to member as template parameter:

```
#include <string>

struct Obj {
    int a,b,c;
};

void bar(int x){}

template<typename T, int (T::*pointerToMember)>
void foo(T o) {
    bar(o.*pointerToMember);
}
int main() {
    Obj x;
    foo<Obj,&Obj::a>(x);
}
```

However, there are different ways that would make the call less verbose. You could pass the member pointer as parameter to be able to deduce it, that would allow to call it as

```
foo(x,&Obj::a);
```

Last not least, you could call `bar` directly

```
bar(x.a);
```